# Why is 他从商店出去了 correct but 他出商店去了 incorrect?

Tags: grammar, difference, direction-complement

- 他出商店去了。
- 他从商店出去了。

Why is only the second sentence right? I knew that when we use a directional complement, we could put the object in the middle between the two verbs. So why do I have to use 从 in this sentence to make it grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

出 and 去 are both verbs, you can't use both as separate entities. 出去 on the other hand is a resultative verb, you can't break it up.

从 (from) is here a preposition indicating direction.

A similar expression would be 他到哪儿去了, where 到 (where/to) is the corresponding preposition.

Answer (score 1):

`出商店去了` is fine with proper context.

Other answers have pointed out that `出去` is an inseparable verb. I don't think it's the case. Instead, you use `出` as a single verb and use `去了` as a complementary. This matches the `Verb Phrase + 去了` structure, as in `钓鱼去了`, `吃午餐去了`.

However, when there is `出` in the verb phrase, people usually expect the `出 + Optional Place + VP + 去了` structure, as in `出钓鱼去了`, `出公司吃午餐去了`. `出商店去了` would sound a bit incomplete in such context.

But then again, we have `出差去了`, `出国去了`, `出门去了` etc. `出差`, `出国`, and `出门` are established verbs, so these phrases fit the `VP + 去了` category. `出国` and `出商店` are too similar in structure, though the latter is not an established word, it is still natural if we mentally consider it it as `VP + 去了`.

I would imagine the following dialog:

> Woman: Have you seen my husband? He wears a green hat. 看见我老公了吗？他戴一顶绿色的帽子。
>
> Girl: Yes, but he just went out of the store. 看见了，不过他刚刚出商店去了。

Not ungrammatical to my taste.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sentence structure that is commonly seen nowadays.  For example:
他买苹果去了
他到美国去了

It means that (he) performed (some action) and he's gone doing it.

In this case, he gets out of the shop and he's gone doing it.
他出商店去了

I think the catch here is to determine if the question is asking if `出去` can be used separately (which we can't), or if it's just a sentence structure where `出` is the action (exiting).